# cannot show label in PyPlot called from Julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I cannot render the label in PyPlot called from Julia. Does anyone know why?

```
using PyPlot
x = 0:0.1:10
y = x.^2
plot(x, y, label="label")
```

The above code renders only the plot without the label. I tried this both at Julia1.0 and Julia0.7, but the results were the same. The working environment is Ubuntu16.04, and I have already installed matplotlib for Python3 in my computer via pip.

Comment: In order to produce a legend you need to call `legend()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, to actually render a legend you have to call `legend()`.

```
using PyPlot
x = 0:0.1:10
y = x.^2
plot(x, y, label="label")
legend()
```

This is not Julia specific but works the same way in Python.